# Why Memory Engine is much larger than InnoDB engine store?

Tags: mysql

I have a table stored about 100,000 rows data in InnoDB engine. I just copy the data to a memory engine table, but I find that the size of the new one is much large than orignal table. Why?

```
| Rows | Engine | Size |

| 96702 | Memory|741MB|

|96952|InnoDB|28MB|
```

WHY?

Comment: Do a show tables on both ?

Answer (score 0):

Memory engine tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length.

**Note:** Loading your data from an InnoDB engine into a Memory engine is really a SQL anti-pattern (because of data duplication). You really should configure the InnoDB buffer pool on your MySQL server. InnoDB will then outperform a Memory engine with many clients because a Memory engine is row locking based

See [the documentation on Memory engine's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Comment: I'm actually doing an ETL operation, which will use the group of data frequently. So I just think store it into memory to avoid repeatly loading from original data. If it's anti-pattern as you said, how can I implement this function?

Comment: I think you should made an new question about your comment with all the details / storage engine / table structure / what data you need / querys even / number off rows / maybe some example data on sqlfriddle, this makes your comment question way to broad to answer without details and maybe even post this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ because database configuration is needed